# lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{9}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n}+\sqrt{3n+3}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> **Question** [image: IIT Jam 2017 India]

**Edit:**

**My Approach:**

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{9}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n}+\sqrt{3n+3}}\right)$

$S_{k}= \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n}+\sqrt{3n+3}}\right) \frac{\left(\sqrt{3n}-\sqrt{3n+3}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{3n}-\sqrt{3n+3}\right)} = \sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3n}-\sqrt{3n+3}}{-3}\right) = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{k}} \left\{ \sqrt{3k+3}\right\} $

$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} S_{k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, by [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), if $a\geq 0$ then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{3k}+\sqrt{3k+a}}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n}+\sqrt{3n+a}}\right)\\
=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{3n}+\sqrt{3n+a}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: okk i got that .thanks

Comment: @Mohan Sharma  The generalization is not always telescopic...

Comment: i will study  Stolz-Cesaro Theorem

Answer (score 5):

We have: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{\sqrt n} \left( \frac1{\sqrt 6 + \sqrt 3} + \frac1{\sqrt 9 + \sqrt 6} +\ldots \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{\sqrt n} \left( \frac{\sqrt 6- \sqrt 3}3 + \frac{\sqrt 9 - \sqrt 6}3 + \ldots \right) $$

Can you see it is a telescoping sum?

Comment: i got that thanks